# Rails if exists update else create using find_or_create_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I am trying to run a method where if a (table Hashtag column tag) tag exists it updates the view count by 1. else it will create a new row with a default view count of 0 and a tag of @hashtag scrubbed.

**Hashlog.rb**

```
def self.create_hashlog(hashtag)        #enters hashtag into the log table, without #. 
        @hashtag_scrubbed = hashtag
        # Hashlog.find_or_create_by_tag(@hashtag_scrubbed) 

        taglog = Hashlog.find_or_create_by_tag(@hashtag_scrubbed) do |t|
        t.count = 0
        end
        taglog.count += 1
        taglog.save!    
    end
```

**Error**

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 772ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass):
  app/models/hashlog.rb:24:in `create_hashlog'
  app/controllers/hashtags_controller.rb:32:in `create'
```

Comment: What happens if you put a bang at the end of `find_or_create_by_tag!()`? This should raise an exception if your new Tag is invalid. Perhaps it will reveal something. Also, perhaps try using `find_or_initialize_by_tag` instead, because you save it anyway at the end of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing it to `find_or_initialize_by_tag` solved it - stephenmurdoch

Answer (score 0):

If your find failed (because there is no record) and your create failed (because the validations failed) the function return nil.